# How to style borders of a div in css

Tags: html, css, sass, border

Could someone help me make an effect like the one in the example below?
I'm trying to put unsuccessful in the responsiveness part ...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyNw2.jpg]

The closest I can get was as follows the code below and the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExTsY.png]

```css
.content .card-l {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid #00ffde;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c9ff04;
  border-left: 2px solid #5bff69;
  border-right: 2px solid #2a43c1;
}

.content .card-l::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #ba6c0e;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d3cc0b;
  border-left: 3px solid #990be6;
  border-right: 3px solid #9a1b3b;
}

.content .card-l::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #070400;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff8f3a;
  border-left: 3px solid #1b9fbd;
  border-right: 3px solid #d87777;
}

.content .card-l .card-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #e0bf95;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #82f577;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1c1f31;
  border-left: 2px solid #d6d254;
  border-right: 2px solid #f380de;
}
.content .card-l .card-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #18fd03;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #34eca3;
  border-left: 3px solid #5528e9;
  border-right: 3px solid #df2cec;
}

.content .card-l .card-content::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #806c53;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of what you tried that was unsuccessful and the code you used in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing and be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider multiple background and `clip-path` like below:

```css
.box {
  --c1:#806c53; /* first color */
  --c2:#5d4e39; /* second color */
  --b:20px; /* border width */
  
  margin:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  font-size:25px;
  outline:3px solid #321f1a; /* outer border */
  border:var(--b) solid transparent;
  padding:3px; /* control the inner border */
  background:
    linear-gradient(#e0bf94 0 0) content-box, /* main background */
    linear-gradient(#321f19 0 0) padding-box; /* inner border */
  position:relative;
}
/* main border */
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:calc(-1*var(--b));
  right:calc(-1*var(--b));
  bottom:calc(-1*var(--b));
  left:calc(-1*var(--b));
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--s1,var(--c1)) 0 0) center/calc(100% - var(--b)) calc(100% - var(--b)) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(var(--s2,var(--c2)) 0 0);
}
.box:after {
  --s1:var(--c2);
  --s2:var(--c1);
  clip-path:
    polygon(0 0,0 100%,var(--b) calc(100% - var(--b)),
              var(--b) var(--b),calc(100% - var(--b)) var(--b),100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text here </div>

<div class="box" style="--b:30px;--c1:red;--c2:darkred;width:300px;"> some text here </div>

<div class="box" style="--b:10px;--c1:blue;--c2:darkblue;width:300px;"> some text here </div>
```

Comment: I'm just having a problem, using :: after I can't click links / buttons inside the card ...
Do you know any solution ??

Comment: @zlDeath try to add `pointer-events:none` ot the ::after/::before elements

Comment: In fact the problem I am having with your solution and the z-index: -1;

Comment: @zlDeath can you share the full code you are using here: https://jsfiddle.net/?  I can then help you update it

Answer (score 0):

here you can find an example

```css
.content {
  border: 2px solid #321f19;
}

.card-l {
  border-top: 4px solid #5d4e39;
  border-right: 4px solid #806c53;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #806c53;
  border-left: 4px solid #5d4e39;
}

.card-content {
  border-top: 4px solid #806c53;
  border-right: 4px solid #5d4e39;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #5d4e39;
  border-left: 4px solid #806c53;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0bf94;
}

.card-content::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 4px); /*remove one border size from the 100%*/
  height: calc(100% - 4px); /*remove one border size from the 100%*/
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #321f19;
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="card-l">
    <div class="card-content">
      <button id="button" class="btn">hello!!!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just having a problem, using :: after I can't click links / buttons inside the card ...
Do you know any solution ??

Comment: try to add position: relative to buttons/links, i've updated the code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using only one div, with no additional containers or spans, taking advantage of [box shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) and the :after [pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

```css
.card-1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 4rem;
  background: #e0bf94;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #321f19; /* outer border */
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #5d4e39 #5d4e39 #806c53 #806c53; /* second border */
  z-index: 1;
}
.card-1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #806c53 #806c53 #5d4e39 #5d4e39; /* third border */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #321f19; /* inner and last border */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-1"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
```

And you can also achieve something pretty similar with nothing but `box-shadow`.

```css
.card-1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 4rem;
  background: #e0bf94;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #5d4e39 #5d4e39 #806c53 #806c53;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #321f19,
    inset -4px 4px 0 0 #806c53,
    inset 4px -4px 0 0 #5d4e39,
    inset 0 0 0 6px #321f19;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: I'm just having a problem, using ::after I can't click links / buttons inside the card ...
Do you know any solution ??

Comment: Yes, just add "z-index: -1;" to the :after element. I edited the code above to reflect it padrinho

Answer (score -1):

You can always put multiple divs to contain different borders.

OR

Use border image in css. It'll be an easier approach if you can find the image. More reference [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-border-image/).

Comment: @zlDeath you need to use an appropirate border image to what you want to create, not just any image. 
Try using this image: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png
With this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp